# entitymanger.find executing find query by using primary key of foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want to get an object of EventDate using primary key. Following is the query i'm executing

```
EventData eventData = entityManager.find(EventData.class, eventdataid);
```

After executing this command in console i'm getting the query as

```
select eventsajgj0_.FILE_ID as FILE_ID8_14_0_, eventsajgj0_.id as
id1_12_0_, eventsajgj0_.id as id1_12_1_, eventsajgj0_.CODE as CODE2_12_1_,
eventsajgj0_.DATE as DATE3_12_1_, eventsajgj0_.FILE_ID as FILE_ID8_12_1_,
eventsajgj0_.MILLIS as MILLIS4_12_1_, eventsajgj0_.ORDER_NR as
ORDER_NR5_12_1_, eventsajgj0_.TYPE as TYPE6_12_1_, eventsajgj0_.VALUE as
VALUE7_12_1_ from eventdata eventsajgj0_ **where eventsajgj0_.FILE_ID=?**
order by eventsajgj0_.ORDER_NR
```

Please note the where clause in above query is against file_id(foreign key) and not id(eventdata primary key)

The dao structure is as follows

```
public class EventData implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public EventData() {

        }

        @Id 
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int id;

        @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name="FILE_ID")
        private ApplicationFile file;
       getter & setters

    }

public class ApplicationFile implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    bi-directional many-to-one association to Event
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="file", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @OrderBy("orderNr")
    private List<EventData> eventsajgjd;
    getter & setters
}
```

my question is, why is it querying using file_id and not id when i'm executing a query on eventdata table.

PS:if i change fetch type of ApplicationFile as LAZY then the query executed is on id and not on file_id.

(added from Comment:)

```
CREATE TABLE eventdata (
    ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    FILE_ID int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (ID), 
    KEY eventdata_ibfk_1 (FILE_ID), 
    CONSTRAINT eventdata_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (FILE_ID)
               REFERENCES files (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=297502 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Can you provide the generated SQL?  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables involved.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `eventdata` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FILE_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `eventdata_ibfk_1` (`FILE_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `eventdata_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`FILE_ID`) REFERENCES `files` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=297502 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: And what query is being executed?

Comment: Is the query you listed the only one being executed, and is the `EventData` entity the `find()` call returns the expected one?

Answer (score 1):

I bet because you mapped the `EventData` / `ApplicationFile` bidirectionally (you have an attribute of type `List<EventData>` in `ApplicationFile` entity

So loading an `EventData` means eagerly loading the related `ApplicationFile` and so eagerly loading all related `EventData`.

I suppose that the related ApplicationFile instance is already in EntityManager L1 cache (otherwise the query should join on files table)

Comment: but i tried entitymanger.clear()  just before the entityManager.find().That should clear the cache of entityManager. but it does not work for some reason.